# Unable to inject a provider into the config block

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I can't get the provider injected in my config section, here my code:

```
 <!-- they are placed in that order -->
            <script src="app/components/department/DepartmentController.js"></script>
            <script src="app/components/department/DepartmentProvider.js"></script>
            <script src="app/components/department/DepartmentService.js"></script>


            <script src="app/components/department/support/SupportController.js"></script>
            <script src="app/components/department/support/SupportRouter.js"></script>
```

Department.js

```
var departmentModule = angular.module('module.department', ['ngResource']);

    // departmentModule.controller('DepartmentController', function($scope) {

 //   nothing here

    // });
```

DepartmentService.js:

```
departmentModule.factory('Department', function($http) {

            return {
                getAll : function(){
                        return $http.get('/api/departments');
                    },
                getByName : function(name){
                        return $http.get('/api/department/'+name);
                    }
                };

});
```

DepartmentProvider.js:

```
departmentModule.provider('Department', function() {
     var name = 'marwen';

     this.$get = function() {
         return {
            name: name
         };
     };
});
```

SupportRouter.js :

```
supportModule.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider,DepartmentProvider) {
```

...

I get this error: `Unknown provider: DepartmentProvider`

Comment: i think the `Department` Provider has been overriden by `Department` factory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Department` provider has been overridden by the `Department` service, you need to specify the different name for provider & service, Both can not be with a same name, The latest one will get register. As you are loading service after provider. Service gets register with in Angular App & the provider is not available inside config.

Comment: Yes the name can be ambiguous to angular, but it was not my problem, it's specific to my project structure, thus the code remains the same as the question. the STRANGE thing is that i deleted the provider and i'm working with the factory instead (i just appended 'Provider' to 'Department') and its works now, so i can work either with providers and services?

Comment: that is because in config phase provider accessible with `Provider` suffix..other than config block it would be accessible as `Department` only..so in that case  `Department` service is getting called instead of `Department` Provider..you need to have different name make them use

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `supportModule.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider,DepartmentProvider)` to  `supportModule.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider,Department)`

or change your provider name from `Department` to `DepartmentProvider`